# PhantomJS page-break-inside and last PDF page background

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, phantomjs

I have a PhantomJS script which generates a PDF from an HTML, the HTML contents have some structure separated by "rows" of content (rows as in Bootstrap), I have added the "page-break-inside: avoid" this "rows" of content so the content doesn't cut in the middle of two pages.

The thing I want to do now is to fill the last page background, because the content is dynamic the last page background doesn't fill the entire PDF page, I did some calculations in order to make the html body bigger before rendering based on the body height, but I realize PhantomJS is returning the height based on the viewport size and not the PDF size.

Is there anyway to know the PDF body heigh or any work arround to always fill the latest page background or in the worst scenario to tell phantom to use a background color for all pages?